# How do I enable FreeType support for GD in Google App Engine PHP flexible environment?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gd, freetype, google-app-engine-php

I want to use imagettfbbox function in my php application running on Google App Engine PHP flexible environment, so I have read this documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime#dependencies) and added

```
extension=gd.so
```

to my php.ini file and I get this error.

```
2017/03/18 10:06:34 [error] 59#0: *7 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: [2017-03-18 19:06:34] production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined function App\Managers\imagettfbbox()
```

When I check the php.info in my deployed application, I can see that GD is enabled, but I could not find the FreeType column, so I suppose FreeType is not enabled in my application.

How can I enable FreeType support for GD?

Answer (score 0):

solved. they made a new commit in the repository.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docker/issues/233

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the report! We have just released a new base image so that having a small `php.ini` file is all you need.